# Google map with transparency

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have already worked before with map skins.  In a new project, I would like to display the map transparently on the top of a picture (just maintaining the country + region lines.)

You can see it in the attached example.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far? This will help you get answers, as well as help future visitors understand your problem.

Comment: You could try to load the maps into a div, and then set the transparency of the parent div. But I don't know whether that would work. Also keep in mind that there are still people using browsers that not (fully) support CSS3. So be careful not to create loss of functionality when transparency is unsupported.

Comment: What attached example and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, here is the link with layout. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvyfk2vx7pa7lxp/map.png About the code im just making research about it.. how far is it possible to do it. Thanks Neograph fro the advice